# Mapping A Property Of List<T> Using Automapper

Tags: c#, string, linq, automapper

Using Automapper, I want to map a property that is a List of type Employee using string.Join() to product a comma-delimited string of the names of an employee's rights. Here are the classes I'm using:

```
public class MappedEmployee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RightNames { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Right> Rights { get; set; }
}

public class Right
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the code I have:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, MappedEmployee>()
    .ForMember(d => d.RightNames, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Rights.SelectMany(r => string.Join(", ", r.Name))));

var employee = new Employee
{
    Name = "Joe Schmoe",
    Rights = new List<Right>
    {
        new Right { Name = "Admin" },
        new Right { Name = "User" },
    }
};

var mappedEmployee = Mapper.Map<Employee, MappedEmployee>(employee);
```

However, this it's producing the folowing:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2[Employee.Right,System.Char]
```

What can I do do get a comma-delimited string of the Employee's rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ResolveUsing` instead and putting `string.Join` before the selection:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, MappedEmployee>()
    .ForMember(d => d.RightNames, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => string.Join(", ",s.Rights.Select(r =>  r.Name))));
```

Comment: That produces the same result.